# Loading JSON Asynchronously and displaying Activity Indicator View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, json, ios4

I am downloading a JSON feed asynchronously in my App Delegate class. Now the data is taking a while to load, so my table view appears empty at first, and then populates a few seconds after. Therefore, I would like to either:

1- Find out what is causing this delay. Therefore, keep all the activity in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and only load the VC after everything has been loaded.

OR

2- Display an activity indicator until the table populates the data.

Now in the first scenario, I am pretty sure that I am pushing the view controller at the wrong time. I tried playing around with it but it seems that that is the only way my app will build and run.

In the second scenario, I would like to know which "connection" method gets invoked first, and which one last. Therefore, I will be able to start up the activity indicator view at the first method and release at the end of the last method.

Below is my code. Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
        [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
     [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                      initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                      message:@"Please check your network connection and relaunch the application" 
                      delegate:self 
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                       otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if ([responseString isEqualToString:@"Unable to find specified resource."]) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to find specified resource.n");
    } 

        else {

        ListingsViewController *listingsViewController = [[ListingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListingsViewController" bundle:nil];
        listingsViewController.jsonData = responseString;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:listingsViewController animated:NO];
        [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:listingsViewController] animated:NO];
        [listingsViewController release];
     }

    [connection release];
    [responseData release];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Start the HTTP request
    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.shoofeetv.com/iphonexml/view/all_channels.json"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    // Display the navigation controller
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with option 2. It's good UI design to display things as quickly as possible, even though the UI might not be useful until the data has loaded it will at least make users of your application feel like something is happening.

Pop the UI in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, display an activity indicator and in connectionDidFinishLoading hide and destroy the activity indicator.

I would also recommend wrapping all the async http request logic in to another class, and have it accept a delegate, then for example you could call:

```
{
   // Show activity indicator
   [httpClient get:@"www.example.com/json" withDelegate:self];
}

-(void)httpClientSuccessful:(NSData*)response
{
   // hide activity indicator
}
```

Comment: Wrap all the aysnc http request into another method or another class? Do you know where I can find a good tutorial on objective-c http async methods? I've looked everywhere and I don't seem to understand it well yet. Thank you..

Comment: In to another class - For example call it HttpClient. Honestly the best place to look is the apple docs http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html - Have a read through all the methods you can implement and what each one does. If you really can't understand it (Or simply cannot be bothered) have a look at http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use - Specifically the async stuff. It's a nice wrapper class around NSURLConnection and should make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 is certainly the correct way to go. You should never block the UI until a network operation has finished. If you have poor reception, you don't want an unresponsive app for several seconds. The user will kill it.

The `NSURLConnection` delegate methods are called in the order `didReceiveResponse`, `didReceiveData` (possibly several times), `connectionDidFinishLoading`. `didFailWithError` can be called any time.

I've successfully used a pattern where I immediately create and display the table view. As long as the data hasn't been loaded, I display a single table cell with an activity indicator and a text saying "Loading data...".

**Update:**

Here's some code (just the essential parts). The main idea is to manage the current state, either not loaded, loading, failed or ready:

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController<NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
    NSInteger state;
    NSURLConnection* connection;
    MyData* data;
}

...
@end

@implementation MyViewController

typedef enum LoadingState {
  eNotLoaded,
  eLoading,
  eFailed,
  eReady
} LoadingState;

- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear: animated];
  // Start loading the data when the table view appears for the first time
  if (state == eNotLoaded) {
    NSURLRequest request = // create the request
    connection = [NSURLConnection initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [request release];
    state = eLoading;
  }
}

- (void) connection: (NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveData: (NSData*) data
{
  // record and process the received data
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection*) connection
{
  // parse the received data and store it into 'data'
  [connection release];
  connection = nil;

  // state changed; redisplay the table view
  state = eReady;
  [[self tableView] reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger) section
{
  if (state == eReady) {
    return [data numberOfRows];
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}

- (UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
  static NSString* DefaultCellIdentifier = @"Default";

  UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: DefaultCellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: DefaultCellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }
  if (state == eReady) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [data labelAtRow: indexPath.row]; 
  if (state == eLoading) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading...";
  } else {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Failed";
  }
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: You Said: "I've successfully used a pattern where I immediately create and display the table view. As long as the data hasn't been loaded, I display a single table cell with an activity indicator and a text saying "Loading data..."." How ??? Any Details??

Comment: I've added some code. It's just the essential parts to explain the pattern. A real solution will have to deal with connection failures, leaving the view before the data has been loaded, proper cleanup, reloading of data etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `NSURLConnection` class method [sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest%3aqueue%3acompletionHandler%3a) which was really helpful and straight forward.

It lets me send a block as a callback for analysing error or success for the specified request:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (!error) {
                                [self parseData:data];
                           } else {
                               NSLog(@"ERROR %@", error);
                           }

                       }
];
```

This way I can activate the activity indicator prior calling the method and remove it once the data is retrieved and at the same time I can handle errors.

I hope this helps ;)